# How to convert the value_list to list in Django

Tags: python, django, list

Hi I have the values_list as follows:

```
x = [(u'All',), (u'C4DI',), (u'C4MI',), (u'TBAZ_DI',), (u'TBAZ_FI',), (u'TTAZ_DI',), (u'TTAZ_FI',)]
```

How to convert this values_list to a normal list like

```
[Al, C4, C4, ...]
```

Any idea guys? I tried

```
y = list(x)
```

But that didnt worked. Guys how can I do that?

Comment: can you post your Model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you want only the first 2 characters in the list:

```
>>> x = [(u'All',), (u'C4DI',), (u'C4MI',), (u'TBAZ_DI',), (u'TBAZ_FI',), (u'TTAZ_DI',), (u'TTAZ_FI',)]
>>> [str(i[0][:2]) for i in x]
['Al', 'C4', 'C4', 'TB', 'TB', 'TT', 'TT']
```

**EDIT:** If you are using `flat=True` (As given in [yedpodtrztiko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35449055/2932244)) then use the following code:

```
[str(i[:2]) for i in x]
```

Where `x = [u'C4DI', u'C4MI', u'All', u'TTAZ_DI', u'TBAZ_DI', u'TTAZ_FI', u'TBAZ_FI']`

Comment: I get this Jason, `['C', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T']`

Answer (score 3):

use the parameter `flat=True` to get a flatten list straight away:

```
Model.objects.values_list('column', flat=True)
```

Comment: Hi Yed: I tried it. But i get values like `[u'C4DI', u'C4MI', u'All', u'TTAZ_DI', u'TBAZ_DI', u'TTAZ_FI', u'TBAZ_FI']`

Comment: so if I get it right, there are two different problems. First: you dont want a nested list. Second: you want modify the values you get. Oh, actually three problems: you want also a different order of the values?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this all so, here I am using str() which convert unicode to str

```
y = [str(a[0]) for a in x]
y
['All', 'C4DI', 'C4MI', 'TBAZ_DI', 'TBAZ_FI', 'TTAZ_DI', 'TTAZ_FI']
```

Comment: Thats a good one Vikram. But its giving me only the first alphabet. Actually I want ['Al', 'C4', 'C4', ...]. Means first 2 characters

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one

```
y = [str(a[0][:2]) for a in x]
```

You want first two character, then I just slice with 2
[image: see the python shell I tried]

Comment: Tried Savad, but get this `['C', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T']`

Comment: @vellattukudy Please make sure you sliced with [:2]

Comment: If `x = [(u'All',), (u'C4DI',), (u'C4MI',), (u'TBAZ_DI',), (u'TBAZ_FI',), (u'TTAZ_DI',), (u'TTAZ_FI',)]` and `y = [str(a[0][:2]) for a in x]` then **`y`** should be **`['Al', 'C4', 'C4', 'TB', 'TB', 'TT', 'TT']`**

Comment: `x = m.values_list('layer1', flat=True)
        y = [str(i[0][:2]) for i in x]
        print y`  printed `['C', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T']`   print x printed `[u'C4DI', u'C4MI', u'All', u'TTAZ_DI', u'TBAZ_DI', u'TTAZ_FI', u'TBAZ_FI']`

Comment: @vellattukudy please open your python shell and try. It should be `['Al', 'C4', 'C4', 'TB', 'TB', 'TT', 'TT']` .

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this using list comprehension:

```
x = [(u'All',), (u'C4DI',), (u'C4MI',), (u'TBAZ_DI',), (u'TBAZ_FI',), (u'TTAZ_DI',), (u'TTAZ_FI',)]

q = [str(i[0] + i[1]) for a in x for i in a]
```

Comment: Nivedita, got error `IndexError: string index out of range`

Comment: Have you tried  Models.object.values_list('name', flat=True)

Comment: Tried Nivedita. Anyways the answer is `[str(i[:2]) for i in x]` :)

Comment: Very glad to see someone from India with good knowledge in Djnago

Comment: Thanks Vellattukudy :)